# What is a word that means a collection of a set of smaller collections, that does not use "super" (or "sub" for the smaller collection)?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a pair of words that essentially means "super-collection" and "collection" where the super-collection contains a set of collections. (Alternatively, could be thought of as a "collection" which contains a set of "sub-collections".) I want the words to NOT use either "super" or "sub". I'm open to general English or jargon from specific domains.

Example usage:

> Ok, we've got five _<collections>_ – let's group them together into a _<super-collection>_.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need to avoid *super-* and *sub-* ?

Comment: @choster -- it will be used in a casual context where it should be as concrete and intuitive as possible while avoiding wordiness and any impression of being technical or legalistic

Comment: They could be [grouped into an **aggregate**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22grouped+into+an+aggregate%22), for example. Or google **synonym superset aggregate** and take your pick.

Comment: I can think of nothing more common and intuitive than *super-* and *sub-*. Surely *hyper-* and *hypo-*, *supra-* or *sur-* and *infra-* or *parv-*,  and *over-* and *under-* would be more technical and/or legalistic.

Comment: Why not just say that the smaller collection is a ***set*** and a  collection of sets is a ***group***.

Comment: I agree with @choster - a set and a superset seem to be graspable by anyone even those who are non-technical.

Comment: @Jim: No, *superset* and *subset* are not at all the critters being asked about. *A* is a superset of *B*, and *B* is a subset of *A*, if every element of *B* is an element of *A*. What the OP is asking about is a set of sets, not a set that contains the same elements and possibly more. The  key words in the question are *set of collections*.

Comment: For a more current-slang choice: set and megaset, or set and uberset?

Comment: And no, I know of no terms, jargon or not, that accurately reflect what is being asked for. To be accurate and clear, you have to, IMHO, say *collection of collections* (or *set of sets*), to get across the levels of hierarchy you want.

Comment: @Drew - What part of “*I'm looking for a pair of words that essentially means "super-collection" and "collection" where the super-collection contains a set of collections.*” doesn’t match *set* and *superset*?

Comment: @Jim: It's these parts of the question that do not fit that meaning: (1) "*a set of smaller collections*", in the title, and (2) "*contains a set of collections*" in the question body. Those clearly indicate a set (or collection) of sets (or collections), and not just a set (or collection) that contains the same members (and possibly more).

Comment: @Ghopper21 what are the things that you are grouping together?  Documents, people, buildings, plants, etc?

Comment: fool's errand people. A fool's errand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question asks for abstract *[collective nouns](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun)* that have an intuitive hierarchy, with one word each for what in mathematics would be called a "set" and "set of sets."

**Approach 1**: Use a  collective noun with a suffix for the second "set of sets" term in order to emphasize the higher-order act of bringing-together.

- We combined five **groups** into an **aggregation**.
- We combined five **sets** into a **collection**.

**Approach 2**: Use a more specific collective noun for the set, and a more general for the set of sets. The question is carefully phrased to avoid the domain of the set items / objects, however if there *is* a domain then this would be a good strategy.

- From the photos we combined five **albums** into a **collection**.
- From the auction items we combined five **lots** into a **collection**.

Comment: It would be appealing if we could use shorter and longer words with an implicit relationship to imply the hierarchy, but combining _lots_ into an _allotment_ isn't clear, and a _collection_ of  _lects_ is nonsense.

Comment: Thanks. This morning I thought of "neighborhood" and "block" which of course is very domain-specific.

Answer (score 1):

**Lot**

> let's group them together into a lot

Definition:

> Noun, informal
>
> a particular group, collection, or set of people or things

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, your question reminds me of how Russell and Whitehead defined "number". As I remember it, a "number" is "the class of all classes equivalent to the given class".

I see no reason you can't use *collection* to characterize a set of smaller collections.

Dictionary.com:

> [*collection*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/collection?s=t):
>   something that is collected

If the "something that is collected" is a *collection*, the result remains a *collection*.

Your example:

> Ok, we've got 5 *collections* -- let's group them together into a
>   *collection*.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are open to language from specific domains how about **clan** or **tribe**?

> Ok, we've got five families – let's group them together into a *clan* or
>   *tribe*.

Comment: Downvoter could you explain so I may be a better contributor?

Answer (score -2):

What about using parent & child

> "Ok, we've got 5 **children** -- let's group them together into a **parent**."

Answer (score -2):

While this is a suffix, not a word, you could look in to using **-ana** to form the word you want. Depending on the nature of the collections, you might be able to use the suffix **-ana** to make a word that describes the larger collection. [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ana)'s definition for the suffix is

> a suffix that forms collective nouns denoting an assembly of items, as household objects, art, books, or maps, or a description of such items, as a bibliography, all of which are representative of or associated with the place, person, or period named by the stem:
>   Americana; Shakespeareana; Victoriana.

Using the suffix along with the person/place/etc. that is the topic of each collection could, depending on the context, make a specific word for a specific situation, but doesn't make a general word to describe a collection of collections.